# Missing field after update cache vue-apollo

Tags: vue.js, graph, apollo, vue-apollo

,

I have a mutation that work great and fortunately I make my apollo cache get update too, but for some reason I get a warning at console that say `Missing field` anything I put after `last_name` at my update query.

my method:

```
createUser() {
  
  this.$apollo
    .mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation(
          $first_name: String!
          $last_name: String!
          $email: String!
          $phone: String!
          $company: String!
          $company_id: String!
          $password: String!
          $roll: Roll!
        ) {
          newUser(
            first_name: $first_name
            last_name: $last_name
            email: $email
            phone: $phone
            company: $company
            company_id: $company_id
            password: $password
            roll: $roll
            blocked: Activo
          ) {
            _id
            company
            first_name
            last_name
          }
        }
      `,
      // Parametros que vienen de mi model
      variables: {
        first_name: this.U_name,
        last_name: this.U_lastName,
        email: this.U_email,
        phone: this.U_phone,
        company: localStorage.company,
        company_id: localStorage.company_id,
        password: this.tempPass,
        roll: this.U_roll
      },
         update: (cache, { data: { newUser } }) => {
          const GETTEAM = gql`
      query getSellersData($id: ID!) {
      getDeveloper(id: $id) {
        _id
        sellers_team {
          _id
          first_name
          last_name
          email
        }
      }
    }
    `
          const data = cache.readQuery({ query: GETTEAM, variables:{id: localStorage.company_id} })
          data.getDeveloper.sellers_team.push(newUser)
          cache.writeQuery({ query: GETTEAM, data })
      },
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.tempId = data.data.newUser._id;
      this.newnotification(
        data.data.newUser._id,
        data.data.newUser.first_name,
        data.data.newUser.last_name
      );
      this.addUserToCompany()
      this.popupActive = true
      this.getTeam()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

So this work but I get this warning example:

```
 invariant.esm.js?a957:29 Missing field email in {
  "_id": "5f4486e9d0e526024f7db668",
  "company": "Dana",
  "first_name": "Geo",
  "las
```

, if I remove the missing fields from my query It won't show on my UI.